# How to sample equally spaced points from huge datapoints

Tags: matlab, interpolation, curve-fitting, knn

I have a dataset containing 1k to 10k points. These points follow certain nonlinear curve (2D or 3D) or 3D surface. A sampling of equidistant points is required (say 100, 200 or 500).

An approach: Sorting and equal interval sampling do not yield a good result, since the curve is nonlinear. It works only when the curve is 2D and symmetric.

As an example, `z=x^3+x*y^2, x=[0, 1], y=[-1, 3]`.

How to sample equidistant points from large dataset using Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to do. From what you wrote I assume the following MATLAB functions would help:
https://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html
https://se.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html?s_tid=doc_ta